# Using MPI.Net causes VS2012 unit test to fail when run, but succeed when debugged

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mpi

I'm using MPI.Net for a Visual Studio 2012 project.  All the unit tests (standard Microsoft Unit test project) fail if they are run, but succeed when they are debugged.  I created a dummy project that has a single class (that just returns "foo") and have replicated the issue.  It appears that the MPI environment is finalized before I actually do anything.  I've tried adding a Sleep in the appropriate place to see if it was timing issues, but it seems to be something else.  Has anyone had any experience with this?

My test method is:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string[] args = null;
        using (MPI.Environment mpiEnv = new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {
            if (MPI.Environment.Finalized)
            {
                throw new Exception("mpi finalized");
            }
            else
            {
                MPIdotNetUnitTestIssue.Class1 bar = new MPIdotNetUnitTestIssue.Class1();
                Assert.AreEqual("foo", bar.Foo());
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception occurs if the test is "run", the test passes if it is "debugged", even with no breakpoints.